# Unir dos consultas de diferentes tablas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito encontrar la manerera para poder unir estas dos consultas para que sean una sola, esta es mi primera consulta, que me trae el numero de ausencia por meses entre 2018 y 2019

```
 SELECT  monthname(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) AS mes, month(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) as numbermes,
sum(pa_ausentismo.horas_aus) as ausencia 
FROM  pa_ausentismo
WHERE date_format(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus, "%y")  between 18 and 19  AND pa_ausentismo.status = 1 
group by numbermes
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi segunda consulta, que me trae el total de colaboradores por meses

```
SELECT MonthName(pr_employees.doa) AS mes, count(*) as collaborators, month(pr_employees.doa) as numbermes 
      FROM pr_employees
      WHERE pr_employees.status = 1  AND DATE_FORMAT(pr_employees.doa, '%Y') BETWEEN 1988 AND 2019
      group by mes
      ORDER BY numbermes
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción es utilizar cada una de tus consultas como una subconsulta y relacionar ambas por medio del número de mes, así:

```
select ausencias.mes as  mes, ausencias.membermes as membermes, ausencias.ausencia as ausencia, empleados.collaborators as collaborators
from (
        SELECT  monthname(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) AS mes, month(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) as numbermes, sum(pa_ausentismo.horas_aus) as ausencia 
        FROM  pa_ausentismo
        WHERE date_format(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus, "%y")  between 18 and 19  AND pa_ausentismo.status = 1 
        group by numbermes
    ) as ausencias,
    (
        SELECT MonthName(pr_employees.doa) AS mes, count(*) as collaborators, month(pr_employees.doa) as numbermes 
        FROM pr_employees
        WHERE pr_employees.status = 1  AND DATE_FORMAT(pr_employees.doa, '%Y') BETWEEN 1988 AND 2019
        group by mes        
    ) as empleados
where ausencias.membermes = empleados.membermes
order by ausencias.numbermes
```

Esto te debería dar un resultado así:

```
mes         numbermes   ausencia    collaborators
January         1       4552.25     163
February        2       4363.59     132
...
December        12      2074.50      77
```